# Drupal custom coding checkout redirect not working

Tags: commerce

I have used custom coding to add a product into a cart.

```
 $items['buynow/%'] = array(
    'title' => t('buynow'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('custom_module_my_form3',1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
function custom_module_my_form3($form, &$form_state,$id) {
global $user;
$product_id=$id;
$product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
$quantity=1;
$line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, $quantity);
$line_item_added = commerce_cart_product_add($user->uid, $line_item);
$order_id=$line_item_added->order_id;
drupal_goto('checkout/'.$order_id);
}
```

Product added succesfully in the cart but redirecting into checkout page doesn't work.It redirecting into home page.

I have created link for each product like `buynow/product_id`. I have also created a custom menu path like `buynow/%`.

After that put the above code in the callback by passing argument.

Comment: why you try use form where there is not any form element in your form !!!!
do it with just menu callback handler, check my answer agian

Answer (score 1):

Your fault is want using `drupal_goto` in form builder!!!

Change your code to this

```
 $items['buynow/%'] = array(
    'title' => t('buynow'),
    'page callback' => 'custom_module_my_form3',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

function custom_module_my_form3() {
   global $user;
   $id=arg(1);
   $product_id=$id;
   $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
   $quantity=1;
   $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, $quantity);
   $line_item_added = commerce_cart_product_add($user->uid, $line_item);
   $order_id=$line_item_added->order_id;
   drupal_goto('checkout/'.$order_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Rajeev you're welcome, I think you are in submit handler, I update my answer with another solution.try it

Comment: I have used it.But no use brother.order created and product added cart successfully.still it redirecting to home page.

Comment: @Rajeev you test my code and it redirect you to home page?

Comment: Yes, I have  tested.It's redirecting to home page. Is there any problem in code on adding product to cart

Comment: it is strange , comment every line in function and just let `drupal_goto('testaddress');` , I think there is a rule (or something like it) that redirect user after  a product added to cart

Comment: I think it's the problem of creating cart order.Because when i enter /checkout/26, i am redirecting to home page.

Comment: Is there any option of buy now button with add to cart. I wish to use both buttons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32994/discussion-between-rajeev-and-zhilevan).